# Leaving a gap between page content and the window's left and right border

Tags: php, html, css

How do I leave a gap between page content and the window's left and right border? When I use:

```
BODY {
  padding-left: 30px  
  padding-right: 30px  
}
```

the header and footer also move? 
(My content is within a php code)

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because your header and footer are also in the body (in fact everything that you can see is in the body)

You just need to wrap your page's content in a `div` (or any Html5 div tag, i.e.`section`), give it a class and add the padding.

```
<body>
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
    <div class="footer">...</div>
<body>

//--- In you .css ---//
.content{
    padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: so i need to have more than one body

Comment: Well, your page can only have one `<body>` tag, which you divide into multiple `<div>`, so you won't apply the padding directly on the body but on the div which contains the content you want to "pad"